# Site content loads but is unresponsive

Tags: html, css

I was developing my site and it was going great, but suddenly it stopped working and I can't use `margins` or anything for my development process :(

By stopped working i mean: "The buttons don't work within my navigation - and the margins I try to add in the css for the sections below the initial page cover"

Here's the code of my website:

http://jsfiddle.net/q2CXH/

EDIT: It works in JS Fiddle but not my website! Any idea why? :(

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="Ryan Shah" />

        <title>Space Bucket | Home</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="introduction">
                <div class="introductory-message">
                    <h1>Space Bucket</h1>
                    <hr />
                    <h3>An amateur game studio</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="navigation-section">
                <ul class="nav-horizontal">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="section">
                <h1>Who are we?</h1>
                <hr />
                <blockquote>
                    About us information goes here
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/site.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    @import url("bootstrap-grids.min.css");

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('../font/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Play';
    src: url('../font/Play-Regular.ttf');
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
}
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div {
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.introduction {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background: url(../img/bg.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
.introductory-message {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
}
.introductory-message > h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
}
.introductory-message > hr {
    width: 10%;
    border-top: 5px double #a69257;
}
.introductory-message > h3 {
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.navigation-section {
    background-color: #020202;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.6);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}
ul.nav-horizontal {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.nav-horizontal li {
    display: inline;
}
ul.nav-horizontal a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #a69257;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px double #ceb15a;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.nav-horizontal a:hover {
    color: #ceb15a;
    border: 2px double #a69257;
}

.section {
    background-color: #dee6ec;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.section > h1 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 5em;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.section > hr {
    width: 10%;
    border-top: 5px double #111;
}
.section > blockquote {
    width: 50%;
    border-left: 4px solid #333;
    border-right: 4px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: post your relevant code in your question please :)

Comment: "but suddenly it stopped working" - What stopped working?

Comment: The buttons don't work within my navigation - and the margins I try to add in the css for the sections below the initial page cover

Comment: If it's ok on JSFiddle, you probably have some missing css files or some conflicting css rules on your dev server

Comment: @singe31 check the answer I used below

Answer (score 0):

Apparently according to W3...

This line in the  of my document:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Is 'unacceptable' when writing HTML code

Thanks for all the help though!